# KendoUI export to excel not rending footer properly

Tags: html, asp.net, excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a column on my kendoUi grid that has anchor tags for the entire column including the footer, here is my code for that:

`columns.Bound(p => p.NonFlagged).Title("Non Flagged").Width(100)
               .ClientTemplate(
                "<a onclick='ShowPatientGapDetailsModal(" + "#=MeasureId#" + ")' href='\\#'>#=NonFlagged#</a>")
               .ClientFooterTemplate("<a onclick='ShowPatientGapDetailsModal()' href='\\#'>#=sum#</a>");`

It works fine for all the rows except the footer, which shows the full html anchor tag as you can see here: [image]

Has anyone seen this before or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

it is because grid exports only data. Not templates. For usage templates into excel export you have to use [ExcelExport](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#excel-customization) event.

Here is small code snippet which I hope helps you.
Anyway I didn't work with footers and excel yet but I am sure there will be same rules like with normal data. Probably it will not work as you need but can kick you right direction.

I have met this behaviour when I had checkboxes in cells or datefields etc.

```
excelExport: function (e) {
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < sheet.rows.length; i++) {
        var dataItem = {
            FieldWithMyTemplate: e.data[i].FieldWithMyTemplate, // In e.data are data from row in grid
        };
        var row = sheet.rows[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
                var template = kendo.template(this.columns[j].template);
                row.cells[j].value = template(dataItem);
        }
    }
};
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that in e.Data at first index ([0]) are data from headers. So on the last one will be your footer data.